# Update statement to increment column value

Tags: sql, sybase

Please consider following setup

```
Control Group   Sequence
-------------------------
Cont1   Group1  0
Cont2   Group1  1
Cont3   Group1  2
Cont3   Group2  0
Cont2   Group2  1
Cont1   Group2  2
```

Increment sequence with +1 for sequence >= sequence of cont2 and for respective Group

The result should be

```
Control Group   Sequence
------------------------
Cont1   Group1  0
Cont2   Group1  2
Cont3   Group1  3
Cont3   Group2  0
Cont2   Group2  2
Cont1   Group2  3
```

Can any one help me to construct a SQL query to get above result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this does what you want:

```
update setup
    set sequence = sequence + 1
    where sequence >= (select s2.sequence
                       from setup s2
                       where s2.group = s.group and s2.control = 'Cont2'
                      );
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also try an alternative solution using OUTER APPLY:

```
UPDATE s
    SET s.[Sequence] = s.[Sequence]+1
FROM setup s
OUTER APPLY
(
    SELECT s2.[Sequence]
    FROM setup s2
    WHERE s2.[Group] = s.[Group] AND s2.[Control] = 'Cont2'
)_
WHERE s.[Sequence] >= _.[Sequence]
```

Comment: I see references of OUTER APPLY here (http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp) but with a different syntax perhaps. But the idea is still the same..

Comment: ASE doesn't have outer apply perhaps some other products do - SAP (formerly Sybase) have multiple db products not all support the same syntax. IQ for example has many more built in OLAP/DSS type query constructs which ASE doesn't support.

Comment: It can be used in SQL Anywhere and IQ, but not ASE; OP did not specify his platform.